# HammerJS v2 - setting a hammer setting on a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

Is there a ways to set a HammerJS setting on a specific element? I'm using HammerJS v2.

For instance if I do:

```
Hammer.defaults.touchAction = "pan-y";
```

It sets it on the whole document, but I would like to set this only on a specific div, if possible.